# Entity framework fluent API mapping complex type to column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity **Entity** which has a **Type** property:

```
class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Type UsedType { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use the fluent API to tell EF to map this property to it's **Type.FullName** instead of trying to create a full **Types** table?

**Entities** table expected:

```
Id INT
UsedType TEXT -- Containing the value from Type.FullName string.
```

Comment: You can't. EF doesn't support transformers. The only option is to create an unmapped `Type` property that converts from/to `UsedType`.

Comment: Aah! Awful, I don't like the idea of contaminating my model just to compensate missing functionalities in EF; I would wrap it, but I will have then to wrap all my entities so I might be forced to do as you suggested, thanks.